# Is a weak symbol guaranteed to be zero-initialized if it's not resolved at link time

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, toolchain

```
__attribute__((weak)) void f1();
__attribute__((weak)) void f2();

void f2(){}

int main()
{
    assert(0 == f1); // always true?
    assert(0 != f2); // always true?
}
```

The [GCC's manual page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) is rather vague about whether a weak symbol is guaranteed to be zero-initialized if it's not resolved at link time.

Any definitive reference? Especially nice if it's from GCC's documentation.

Comment: Looking at the examples in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol), it looks like they are indeed relying on this behavior (as in `if (user_hook) user_hook();` )

Comment: It's really a feature of the linker, not the compiler, so I wouldn't necessarily expect it to be fully documented in the GCC manual.  On the other hand GNU ld doesn't seem to discuss weak symbols in depth either.  By the way, the GCC manual you linked is an ancient version.